# Compute a method that computes a shortest K-tree of G with largest possible degree of vertex v0

Tags: graph-theory

I am struggling with computing a concise algorithm to solve the exercise below.

How would you go about it?

**Setup:**
Let G = (V, E) be a connected graph of n+1 vertices v0, v1, . . . , vn
and at least n + K edges K ≥ 1. Note that the set of edges traversed in any
feasible solution to the CVRP (Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem) is a K-tree, provided we either exclude routes that
only visit a single customer or include two edges between the depot node and
such customers. Additionally, in this K-tree defined by a feasible solution to the
CVRP, each customer vertex v ∈ V \ {v0} has degree 2 and the depot vertex v0
degree 2K, if K is the number of routes. Shortest K-trees are thus a tool for
computing lower bounds on the optimal objective value of the CVRP.

**Exercise:**
Give a method that computes a shortest K-tree of G with largest possible
degree κmax of vertex v0. The method should thereby not use any edge
exchanges that increase the degree of v0